# Succinct But Complete Example of WPF App?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, business-objects

Is there a succinct but complete example project or tutorial that brings together the pieces of the Microsoft stack for a complete application?

> ```
> WPF
> MVVM
> Business Objects
> EF
> Database
> ```

I find plenty for WPF and plenty for EF, but am having trouble fully understanding how the EF generated classes relate to business objects, and how those business objects in turn fit into the MVVM pattern.

Comment: There really aren't any complete Application examples in the WPF space yet, however as the technology matures you will probably find the optimum stack to look something like; DB->EF->B.O.->DTO->MVVM->WPF. I would check Pete Brown's blog for the Developer Roundups one will appear eventually http://10rem.net

Comment: When you write EF, do you mean the objects that EF generates from the data model?  How is EF hooked to B.O. and B.O. hooked to the DTO's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found one that does all of those, not succinct anyways, but I have found several that do them separately. One that brings a lot of this into one, and should be your starting point IMO, is the [CAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611%28v=pandp.10%29.aspx) that came out October 2009 for WPF.

As many concepts as you just mentioned I can't imagine a concise tutorial existing for all of those, and being good enough to grasp them.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the sample applications of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. They show:

- View composition
- UI Workflow (Wizards)
- Command binding / Shortcut Keys
- MVVM pattern, Unit Testing
- Validation
- Entity Framework
- Open/Save FileDialog
- Print Preview / Print Dialog
- Localization